# mailx is not sending any mail

Tags: linux, command-line, email, sendmail, mailx

I'm new to super user and I am trying to teach myself how to code bash and work my way around the GNU/Linux operating system. I've become pretty comfortable with vim, emacs and some basic commands but I hit an obstacle. I can not get mailx to actually send mail to any of my email accounts. I haven't installed any additional MTA myself, and I am using sendmail in the background for that purpose. I figure it should work. Sending mail locally works fine but when I send mail to my email addresses I never get any new mail in my inbox.

I've done my best as a newbie to track down the problem, but unfortunately /var/log/maillog doesn't provide any useful clues as it indicates that the mail was sent successfully:

```
Apr  3 21:03:29 darkstar sendmail[4760]: q3413TRL004760: from=andrew, size=231, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201204040103.q3413TRL004760@darkstar.example.net>, relay=andrew@localhost
Apr  3 21:03:29 darkstar sendmail[4761]: q3413Tnu004761: from=<andrew@darkstar.example.net>, size=496, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201204040103.q3413TRL004760@darkstar.example.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr  3 21:03:29 darkstar sendmail[4760]: q3413TRL004760: to=werdnaonaps@gmail.com, ctladdr=andrew (1000/100), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30231, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q3413Tnu004761 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Additionally I am using Slackware 13.37, if that's important.

Comment: set confLOG_LEVEL to 14 in the sendmail configuration file and then test again. update your question with your log results.

Answer (score 2):

If this computer is located on a home network connection, you are likely blocked by your ISP from sending mail directly. Most ISPs expect you to authenticate to their mail server to send mail. In that case, follow [these slackware specific directions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/sendmail-smtp-auth-howto-224543/#post1144343) to set up `Client-Side SMTP AUTH + SMART_HOST`